# RestKit: Property 'mapper' not found on object of type 'RKObjectManager *'

Tags: ios, restkit

Using the new Xcode and RestKit I am facing a problem with the mapper. The error is: Property 'mapper' not found on object of type 'RKObjectManager *'

```
// Initialize RestKit
NSString* baseUrl = @"http:////172.13.12.17:3000";
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseUrl];

RKObjectMapper* mapper = objectManager.mapper;
```

Does someone knows how I could fix this? Thx, Vanessa

Answer (score 2):

On the latest RestKit master branch, object mapping has been completely reworked, such that the mapper property no longer exists on the RKObjectManager class.  You're probably running into issues following an old code example for object mapping that was written prior to the major overhaul of the mapping subsystem.

Comment: Thanks. I am following: http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/
The Examples on the github's RestKit files are also running on errors.
The tutorials on net plus are also old. 
Do you have some links to examples / tutorials that should work?

Comment: The Example projects in the main RestKit repository are all up-to-date, but the tutorial content has yet to be updated since the launch of Object Mapping 2.0.